# ZF2 - Session dump on page change / refresh

Tags: php, apache, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Last week i asked a question which is still unresolved (unfortunately). Here is the link :
[ZF2 empty session container between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967301/zf2-empty-session-container-between-pages)

I'm opening a new question today because i found more understandable clues to explain my problem.

This is very simple :
Zend Framework 2 and/or PHP dump/purge my session containers on every single page load or refresh.
It's even working like this with or without AJAX calls.

Whatever i do, i can't persist my session datas because all is reset permanently.

I tried many things found around the web, like :

- Init Zend Session Manager (with and without SessionConfig)
- Use alternative storages like memcache with Zend\Cache\Storage
- ...

I'm looking around for a solution for more than 2 weeks now ... and i can't find anything to resolve my problem.

I really hope that some of you guys can help me.

Thx

Comment: Can't help you a lot, but this has something to do with the way you configure your server.

Comment: Thx Sam. I'm not sure it comes from the server. Cause i get the same behavior either on my local machine (Mac OS X) and on my distant server (Ubuntu Server).

Comment: Can you see the sessions being created (i.e. can you see data in the session file/session db table)? Does this happen just for you or all users? What session timeout are you using? Without any new info, perhaps you could zip up the minimum amount of code required to repeat the problem for us to download so we can try it out?

Comment: @TimFountain, thx for your answer. Yes i can see data in session file and it happens for all users. The session timeout is set on 30 minutes ... so i don't think it comes from here. If you have a bitbucket account i can give an access to a repo with code to reproduce, tell me what you think about it.

Comment: My bitbucket username is tfountain

Comment: I created a "tests" repo. You have read/write access on it. I left you a test data set. My problem is in the "CetmShop" module. Thx for all in advance

Comment: how are you initializing your session manager ? can you post that code too

Comment: Oops, i didn't commit this and i'm at work now. Whatever, this is not very important because i followed the ZF2 doc (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html) and then when i saw it were not working, i tried this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774809/how-to-bootstrap-sessions-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: By the way, from the stackoverflow solution i found, i added cache_expire => 30 and cache_limiter => public ... but it did'nt work better

Comment: The views and some other things make it a little tricky for me to test your code, but I tried adding data to `$this->sessionCart->foo` and then var_dumping it on another page refresh withing CetmShop and that worked fine. Make sure it's not something silly like the date/time on your server or local machine being wrong (by more than 30 minutes).

Comment: If not, perhaps try the most basic session operation possible: grab a fresh copy of the ZF skeleton app, add something to a session container and try reading it back on another page. That would at least help narrow it down to either an app problem or environment problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my solution, i was adding a `Zend\Db\ResultSet` to the session.
I think, because this object is too huge, it overloads the session ... but this is only a supposition.

Since i replaced the ResultSet storage by an array of Mapper objects, everything works fine.

By the way, i looked around on the internet and i didn't found anything about that kind of problem.

Hope this will help.

Thanks a lot for the help, especially to @TimFountain.

Comment: I have the same problem like you did. However instead of storing Zend\Db\ResultSet, I'm storing simple int. However Session are still wipe out by Zend. Do you have new explanation of this behavior ?

Comment: Nope, I'm sorry. I never had any trouble to store a simple int. Did you check your php config for session ? Server config ?